# Why doesn't motion tracked object show in render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, motion-capture

I copy and pasted an object in one blender file and imported it into a motion tracked scene. However, when I click "render image" the motion tracked object (robot) does not show in the render. I made sure that "transparent" was toggled on, and have checked the nodes, yet the object still does not show in the render. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer, but did the motion tracked scene render before you imported in the object?

I didn't see anything obviously wrong in the file, but I copied all your collections and created a new scene inside the same file, pasted the collections in there and the renders worked. So something was odd with your scene.

Sorry I don't have a solution for you but copying it into a new scene seems to work, otherwise you could bake the camera to keyframes and just append everything into a new file, that should also work.

Comment: Oh, it did not! I will try doing that before importing and tell you the results. Thank you.

Comment: To be clear, when you did this did the object show in the scene? Or did it just show the object.

Comment: Sorry I'm not clear on what you are asking about showing the object. But to reiterate when I opened your file I couldn't render your character or any new objects I created, it always just rendered blank. So I created a new scene in the file and copy pasted the collections into the new scene, and it would then render all the objects fine.